# access amazon S3 bucket from hadoop specifying SecretAccessKey from command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

I am trying to access amazon S3 bucket using hdfs command. Here is command that I run:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls s3n://<ACCESSKEYID>:<SecretAccessKey>@<bucket-name>/tpt_files/
-ls: Invalid hostname in URI s3n://<ACCESSKEYID>:<SecretAccessKey>@<bucket-name>/tpt_files
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -ls [-d] [-h] [-R] [<path> ...]
```

My `SecretAccessKey` includes “/”. Could it be cause of such behavior?

In the same time I have aws cli installed in this server and I can access my bucket using aws cli without any issues (AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey configured in .aws/credentials):

```
aws s3 ls s3:// <bucket-name>/tpt_files/
```

If there any way how to access amazon S3 bucket using Hadoop command without specifying Keys in core-site.xml? I’d prefer to specify Keys in command line.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The best practice is run hadoop on an instance created with an EC2 Instance profile role, and the S3 access is specified as a policy of the assigned role. Keys are no longer needed when using the instance profile.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/java-sdk/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html

You can also launch AMIs with an Instance profile role and the CLI and SDKs will use it.   If your code uses the DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain class, then  credentials can be obtained through environment variables, system properties, or credential profiles file (as well as EC2 Instance profile role).